# What is the parameter for request and response body okhttp in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, parameters, okhttp

I start to code the app in kotlin with okhttp3. I get response body but how I can get the info that I need? For example, I use [Google example](https://api.github.com/users/defunkt). I just want to get the "name:". How I can tell my request that I what get only "name:"? Can you help with some code example or some source with instruction and description about OkHTTP? I read official documentation but didn't find something or just didn't understand.

```
fun run(url: String){
        val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
        //client.authenticator()
        val client = OkHttpClient()
            .newBuilder()
            .addInterceptor { chain ->
                val originalRequest = chain.request()
                val builder = originalRequest
                    .newBuilder()
                val name = request.header("name")
                    //.header("Authorization",
                    //    Credentials.basic("login", "password"))
                val newRequest = builder.build()
                chain.proceed(newRequest)
            }.build()

client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback{
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                
                toast("fail")
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                
                textView3.setText(response.body()?.string())
                
            }
        })
```

I tried to use `.header("name")` but it was red and I think I make some mistake.
Thank for every suggestions

Comment: usually an API is designed to provide a response based on a defined schema. If the client app receives more information in the body, then it has to filtered out the not-required part and use only the needed part of the response.

Comment: @sudipn Can you help me how I can filter response? I need to write tag in header like `.header("success")` or `.header("username")`, is it right?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it with **Jackson ObjectMapper**

as per your example, let's say you receive the following *content* in the response:

```
{
  "login": "defunkt",
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Chris Wanstrath",
  "company": null,
  "blog": "http://chriswanstrath.com/"
}
```

but you are only interested to in the `name` field, therefore you define a `User` class:

```java
public class User { private String name; }
```

and then using the `ObjectMapper` configured to ignore the missing properties:

```java
// content = response.body().string();

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
try {
    User user = mapper.readValue(content, User.class);
    System.out.println(user.getName());    // Chris Wanstrath
} catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```